# Send blob data trough XHR from client to NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I want to send a blob data from JA client to NodeJS server.

Now I have this client-side code:
    [...]
    recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        audioObj = blob;
    });

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("operation", "addMessage");
formData.append("msg", audioObj);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/sendRecord", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
        // get response from server
    }
}
xhr.send(formData);
```

I use some JS library to record audio from integrated microphone, and at the end I have a audioObj that is a blob object.

And this si node.js server that I want to adjust for receiving data.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response){

    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    // check the url path
    if (path == "/sendRecord") {

        // check the request method
        if(request.method != "POST"){
            // return error
        }

        // _______________________________
        //| here I want catching XHR data |
        // –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
    }
}).listen(8080);

console.log("Server running on: http://localhost:8080/");
```

I think should be some server-side XHR API for responding to the client XHR request, but I don't know which and where to find they.
Could anyone help me? also whit link or documentation... ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

Comment: Good... sound good!
Tomorrow I will cheek it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer to myself... If anyone find useful in future ;)

Using Formidable (https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) I've done this:

```
var http = require('http'),
  url = require('url'),
  formidable = require('formidable')
  util = require('util');

var server = http.createServer().listen(8080);

server.on('request', function(request, response) {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
    fields = [],
    files = [];

  form.on('error', function(err){
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('error:\n\n' + util.inspect(err));
  });

  form.on('field', function(field, value){
    console.log(field, value);
    fields.push([field, value]);
  });

  form.on('file', function(field, file){
    console.log(field, file);
    files.push([field, file]);
  });

  form.on('end', function(){
    console.log('-> upload done');
    response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write('Received fields:\n\n ' + util.inspect(fields));
    response.write('\n\n');
    response.end('received files:\n\n ' + util.inspect(files));
  });

  form.encoding = 'utf-8';
  form.uploadDir = './tmp';
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(request);
});
```

Thanks to robertklep for the suggestion!